# Why does method reference needs a type casting to a Function interface?

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

In this code snippet my IDE *(IDEA Intellij Community)*  suggesting to cast method reference to Function Interface.

Why is that ?

```
 public class MethodReferences {

    public static void main(String[] strings) {
        Function<String, Integer> f = Integer::parseInt;

        Predicate<Person> personPredicate = p->convert(p.getAge(),Integer::parseInt) >10;

        //This is fine 
        System.out.println(convert("123", f));

        //This is fine
        System.out.println(convert("123", (Function<String, Integer>) Integer::parseInt));

        //This is NOT
        System.out.println(convert("123", Integer::parseInt)); //x1
    }

    private static <T, S> T convert(S s, Function<S, T> stFunction) {
        return stFunction.apply(s);
    }
}
```

The Error message I get in line `x1` is:

```
Error:(20, 19) java: reference to println is ambiguous
  both method println(char[]) in java.io.PrintStream and method println(java.lang.String) in java.io.PrintStream match

Error:(20, 35) java: incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
    inferred: java.lang.Integer
    upper bound(s): char[],java.lang.Object
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with `Integer::parseInt` returning an `int` rather than an `Integer`

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this with JDK 1.8.0_51. My code compile and gives the output. What version of JDK are you using?

Comment: @SMA the code is not compilable ...

Comment: What is your IDE? I'm enable to reproduce this on Eclipse Mars.

Comment: @Mistalis Idea Intellij

Comment: This is an interesting Question. Don't just downvote it without knowing the real reason behind this

Comment: The cast provides a _target type_ for the method ref, which factors into overload resolution.  With the target type, there is only one applicable overload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not accepted because parseInt method has two different types.

One of them is only accept one `String` argument, other one accept one `String` and one `int` type:

`static int parseInt(String s)`

`static int parseInt(String s, int radix)`

In your code, you are using second one, so you should cast to that. In Eclipse, as I know, the IDE automatically understand what it belongs; but in IntelliJ, you should do that type casting for secure and good programming.

Comment: That's not what I see. NB I had to add a class `Person` with `getAge()` returning `String` to reproduce, at which point javac reports ambiguity between `println(char[])` and `println(String)`, for which I don't see an easy explanation. OTOH, `parseInt(String,int)` is out of the reckoning, because an implementation of `R Function.apply(T)` can only take one argument.